# Syntax error in pivoting a SQL Server table using VARCHAR columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table (~50m rows) like below in SQL Server:

```
PId        CustomColumnName        CustomColumnValue
1          PropertyA               1
1          PropertyB               B
1          PropertyC               C
2          PropertyA               1.5
2          PropertyB               BB
2          PropertyC               CC
3          PropertyD               D1
3          PropertyA               2.0
```

I'd like to `PIVOT` that table to look something like this:

```
PId    PropertyA    PropertyB    PropertyC    PropertyD
1      1            B            C            NULL
2      1.5          BB           CC           NULL
3      2.0          NULL         NULL         D1
```

I know that SQL Server has `PIVOT` function, so I wrote something like this:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM 
  ( 
  SELECT [PId], [CustomColumnName], [CustomColumnValue] 
  FROM [myTable]
  ) AS src
  PIVOT
  (
  MAX([CustomColumnValue]) -- Not sure how to aggregate VARCHAR data here
  FOR [CustomColumnName] IN ('PropertyA', 'PropertyB', 'PropertyC', 'PropertyD')
  ) AS pvt
```

But I got `Incorrect syntax near 'PropertyA'` error. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible with the `PIVOT` function of SQL Server (because I don't think I can aggregate `[CustomColumnValue]`, which is of `VARCHAR` type). **If using `PIVOT` is not feasible in my use case**, is there an efficient, alternative way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thank you in advanced for your suggestions/answers!

Comment: Take the single quotes out from around the column names `PropertyA`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--remove the Single quotes you will get desired Result     set

```
;With cte(PId, CustomColumnName,CustomColumnValue)
    AS
    (
    SELECT 1,'PropertyA','1'    Union all
    SELECT 1,'PropertyB','B'    Union all
    SELECT 1,'PropertyC','C'    Union all
    SELECT 2,'PropertyA','1.5'  Union all
    SELECT 2,'PropertyB','BB'   Union all
    SELECT 2,'PropertyC','CC'   Union all
    SELECT 3,'PropertyD','D1'   Union all
    SELECT 3,'PropertyA','2.0'
    )
     SELECT *
      FROM 
      ( 
      SELECT [PId], [CustomColumnName], [CustomColumnValue] 
      FROM cte
      ) AS src
      PIVOT
      (
      MAX([CustomColumnValue]) 
      FOR [CustomColumnName] IN (PropertyA, PropertyB, PropertyC, PropertyD)
      ) AS pvt
```

You can generate the same Result Set using Dynamic Pivot.it is as below

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #temp
;With cte(PId, CustomColumnName,CustomColumnValue)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'PropertyA','1'    Union all
SELECT 1,'PropertyB','B'    Union all
SELECT 1,'PropertyC','C'    Union all
SELECT 2,'PropertyA','1.5'  Union all
SELECT 2,'PropertyB','BB'   Union all
SELECT 2,'PropertyC','CC'   Union all
SELECT 3,'PropertyD','D1'   Union all
SELECT 3,'PropertyA','2.0'
)
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM cte

Declare 
         @Sql nvarchar(max),
         @dynamicCol nvarchar(max)
--Create columns Dynamically
SELECT @dynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ QUOTENAME(CustomColumnName )
From  #temp For XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

--SELECT @dynamicCol

SET @Sql='
SELECT [PId] ,'+ @dynamicCol +' From
(
SELECT [PId], [CustomColumnName], [CustomColumnValue]  From
#temp
)AS Src
PIVOT 
(
MAX([CustomColumnValue]) For [CustomColumnName] IN ('+@dynamicCol+')
)
AS Pvt'

PRINT @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing comprehensive answer including the dynamic solution!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes.

> ```
> SELECT * 
>   FROM 
>   ( 
>   SELECT [PId], [CustomColumnName], [CustomColumnValue] 
>   FROM [myTable]
>   ) AS src
>   PIVOT
>   (MAX([CustomColumnValue])
>    FOR [CustomColumnName] IN ([PropertyA], [PropertyB], [PropertyC], [PropertyD])
>   ) AS pvt
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PId | PropertyA | PropertyB | PropertyC | PropertyD
> --: | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
>   1 | 1         | B         | C         | null     
>   2 | 1.5       | BB        | CC        | null     
>   3 | 2.0       | null      | null      | D1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7dd49ef788269bcb0707410b06641cbb)*

Comment: Thank you!! Removing single quotes and treating them as column names works! I accepted the other answer because s/he also provided the solution to dynamic columns. Hope you understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

You require to use quotename of columns

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
  ( 
  SELECT [PId], [CustomColumnName], [CustomColumnValue] 
  FROM [myTable]
  ) AS src
  PIVOT
  (
  MAX([CustomColumnValue]) -- Not sure how to aggregate VARCHAR data here
  FOR [CustomColumnName] IN ([PropertyA], [PropertyB], [PropertyC], [PropertyD])  --provide in squarebrackets if generating dynamic then use quotename() function of sql server
  ) AS pvt
```

Comment: Thank you!! Removing single quotes and treating them as column names works! I accepted the other answer because s/he also provided the solution to dynamic columns. Hope you understand. :)